# ListView option missing in ECLIPSE

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I am working on an android project. I am trying to use listview but this option is missing in my eclipse. What could be the possible cause and how can I get it in my eclipse?

Comment: What happens if you open the XML and write the ListView tag (`<ListView>`)? Then try switching back to the graphical editor.

Comment: Have you clean your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it in xml file manually like:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and see what will happen then.

Comment: No, this did not solve the issue. It does not recognize any of the content in the listview.